# Jenkins always told me "Failed to connect to repository"

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, gitlab

I have already created ssh key and post on the gitlab, but it's still wrong

It's error message:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h -- git@gitlab.com:GoldenMagicDogeGroup/jenkinstest.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: Load key "/tmp/jenkins-gitclient-ssh14005393280406542908.key": invalid format
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

And here is my step:

1. create access token in gitlab
2. generate ssh key in jenkins container
3. post public key on gitlab
4. add credential in jenkins, chose gitlab api token
5. add credential in jenkins, chose ssh username with private key

What's I lack?

And I tried command `git ls-remote -h -- git@gitlab.com:GoldenMagicDogeGroup/jenkinstest.git HEAD`, but it doesn't return anything, I think it maybe is a problem

I also tried command `git ls-remote -- git@gitlab.com:GoldenMagicDogeGroup/jenkinstest.git`, and this is return:

```
2ecdc0c3a369db00c992947642413196e64c8809        HEAD
2ecdc0c3a369db00c992947642413196e64c8809        refs/heads/main
```

Comment: Should use only one approach btw step 4 and 5, if you are usgin gitlab api token (4) you must select this credential on job scm config section.

Comment: Otherwise, Check if the private key start with `----- BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY -----` , and end with  `----- END RSA PRIVATE KEY -----` .